# Trying to Update 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

I am trying to update 12.04LTS on my laptop and for the past couple of days I have been getting this error message:

`W:Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/fullcircle-issue-59/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  The requested URL returned error: 401
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Any ideas?

Comment: It occurs because incompleted purchase of fullcircle magazine,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the repo [Removing & Disabling Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu/#Removing_.26_Disabling_Repositories)